# Definition of boundary points in DBSCAN

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, dbscan

If I understand correctly, DBSCAN is the following method of decomposing a set, which has parameters $\epsilon$ and $k$. Given a set $E$ of points in $\mathbb R^n$, consider the graph $G$ whose vertices are the points of $E$ and where there is an edge between $x$ and $y$ whenever $|x-y| \leq \epsilon$. Consider the subgraph $G'$ consisting of vertices of $E$ of degree at least $k$, and let $C'_1, ... ,C'_N$ be the connected components of $G'$. Let $C_1, ... , C_N$ be subsets of $G$ where a point is in $C_i$ if either it is in $C'_i$ or it is a neighbor of a point in $C'_i$. A point can be in more than one $C_i$. Since a point can be in $C_i$ for more than one value of $i$, if you want the $C_i$ to be mutually disjoint, you have to enforce this by, for example, arbitrarily assigning each point to exactly one of the $C_i$ it belongs to. Points which are not in any $C_i$ are called "noise".

This algorithm seems to have a third parameter $s$ which is not usually stated and is by default set to $1$. This is the number of edges which must be traversed to get from a boundary point to a core point, where $C'_i$ is the set of core points and $C_i \setminus C'_i$ is the set of boundary points. What happens if $s=0$? Or $s=2$? That is, what if we just set $C_i = C'_i$, or what if we say $p \in C'_i$ if there exist $q, r$ such that $p$ neighbors $q$, $q$ neighbors $r$, and $r \in C_i$? Are variations where $s$ is manipulated studied?

One issue with this variation is that if $s=2$, a core point of one cluster could also be a boundary point of another cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Boundary points can always be reachable from more than one cluster, as discussed in the original DBSCAN article as well as in

> Erich Schubert, Jörg Sander, Martin Ester, Hans-Peter Kriegel, Xiaowei Xu:
> DBSCAN Revisited, Revisited: Why and How You Should (Still) Use DBSCAN. ACM Trans. Database Syst. 42(3): 19:1-19:21 (2017)

because of this issue, boundary points are no longer included in clusters in HDBSCAN*.

> Ricardo J. G. B. Campello, Davoud Moulavi, Jörg Sander:
> Density-Based Clustering Based on Hierarchical Density Estimates. PAKDD (2) 2013: 160-172

Instead of adding a heuristic with yet another parameter, it may be worth exploring the relationship to minimum cuts further, discussed in

> Erich Schubert, Sibylle Hess, Katharina Morik:
> The Relationship of DBSCAN to Matrix Factorization and Spectral Clustering. LWDA 2018: 330-334

Comment: We appreciate you contributing your expertise! Please note that if you are the author of a paper cited in an answer, you must disclose your affiliation. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/320588 (Having the same username as the author is not sufficient; you must state that you are the author in the answer.)